# Are there sunnah prayers before Asr and Isha?

Tags: hadith, salat, sunnah

I read Hadith sunnah prayers are : 2 before fajr 4 before zuhr 2 after 2 after Maghrib 2 after Isha

But I was taught those and **also 4 rakat before asr and Isha and when I go to the mosque at those times people do this too.** which I assumed were sunnah and I have been praying them with the sunnah intention

What to do? I’m confused

Comment: The matter is open wide. There are different statements in the sunnah some scholars toke one options others another.

Comment: jazakallah khair

Answer (score 1):

Some of the madhabs such as the [Hanafis](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/669) and [Shafi'is](https://shamela.ws/book/2186/1670) consider these to be recommended optional prayers. They come under the category of *nafal* or *ghair mu’akkadah* type of sunnah.

The evidence for prayer before Asr includes:

> رحم الله امرءا صلى أربعا قبل العصر
>
> May Allah have mercy upon a man who prays four before Al-Asr
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:430)</sup>

And for before Isha includes:

> روي عن عائشة رضي الله عنها أنه عليه السلام كان يصلي قبل العشاء أربعا
>
> Aisha narrated that the Messenger of Allah ﷺ offered four  rak’ahs before Isha
>
> <sup>— quoted in  [مراقي الفلاح شرح نور الإيضاح](https://shamela.ws/book/412/170)</sup>

They are also evidenced by the general meaning of the hadith:

> ‏ بين كل أذانين صلاة ... لمن شاء
>
> There is a prayer between every two calls (i.e. Adhan and Iqama) ... for the one who wants to pray.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:627)</sup>

Comment: jazakallah khair